# How to parse the field value in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have logstash in which I am getting data from HTTP API but there is a field for which I need to parse the value from  this

```
 "ServiceProvider": "T:ISP | CIR:450Mbps BR:1Gbps | VD:Beq | CID:124"
```

to this

```
"ServiceProvider": "T:ISP"
"CIR": "450Mbps"
"BR": "1Gbps"
"VD": "Beq"
"CID": "124"
```

My config file for Logstash is:

```
input{
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      "ISP" => {
         method => get
         url => "http://xyz:8080/api"
         headers => {
           Accept => "application/json"
         }
      }
    }
    request_timeout => 60    
    tags => "hourly"
    schedule => { cron => "30 * * * *"}
    codec => "json"
    metadata_target => "meta"
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
     remove_field => [ "[meta][request][auth][user]", "[meta][request][auth][pass]","[meta][request][headers][Accept]" ]
  } 
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://xyz:9100"]
    index => "xyz"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you sure about `"ServiceProvider": "T:ISP"` ? It seems the closing double quote comes after `CID:124`

Comment: I have  field like this ```"ServiceProvider": "T:ISP | CIR:450Mbps BR:1Gbps | VD:Beq | CID:124" ```. I want it to be like this each separated, 
```"ServiceProvider": "T:ISP"
"CIR": "450Mbps"
"BR": "1Gbps"
"VD": "Beq"
"CID": "124"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would leverage the [`dissect` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html) and [`kv` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) like this:

```
filter {
    dissect {
      mapping => {
        "message" => "%{ServiceProvider} | %{[@metadata][kv]}"
      }
    }
    kv {
      source => "[@metadata][kv]"
      field_split => "| "
      value_split => ":"
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => [ "[meta][request][auth][user]", "[meta][request][auth][pass]","[meta][request][headers][Accept]" ]
    } 
}
```

Comment: Getting read time out error. When applying the above config.

Comment: It's probably not because of the new filters, but because of the http input which provides nothing to read